# XSLT to remove duplicate nodes & extra <Row>

Tags: xml, xslt

I am little stuck in writing an XSLT to remove extra roes and duplicate nodes. SO need your help.

My XML looks like following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<Rowsets CachedTime="" DateCreated="2015-05-05T19:27:06" EndDate="2015-05-05T19:27:06" StartDate="2015-05-05T18:27:06" Version="14.0.0 Build(802)">
    <Rowset>
        <Columns>
            <Column Description="DateTime" MaxRange="0" MinRange="0" Name="DateTime" SQLDataType="93" SourceColumn="DateTime"/>
            <Column Description="" MaxRange="0" MinRange="0" Name="_10LI132.PV" SQLDataType="6" SourceColumn="10LI132.PV"/>
            <Column Description="" MaxRange="0" MinRange="0" Name="_10LQ132.PV" SQLDataType="6" SourceColumn="10LQ132.PV"/>
            <Column Description="" MaxRange="0" MinRange="0" Name="_10TI112.PV" SQLDataType="6" SourceColumn="10TI112.PV"/>
            <Column Description="" MaxRange="0" MinRange="0" Name="_10LI135.PV" SQLDataType="6" SourceColumn="10LI135.PV"/>
            <Column Description="" MaxRange="0" MinRange="0" Name="_10LQ132.PV" SQLDataType="6" SourceColumn="10LQ132.PV"/>
            <Column Description="" MaxRange="0" MinRange="0" Name="_10LI127.PV" SQLDataType="6" SourceColumn="10LI127.PV"/>
            <Column Description="" MaxRange="0" MinRange="0" Name="_10TI112.PV" SQLDataType="6" SourceColumn="10TI112.PV"/>
            <Column Description="" MaxRange="0" MinRange="0" Name="_10LQ127.PV" SQLDataType="6" SourceColumn="10LQ127.PV"/>
        </Columns>
        <Row>
            <DateTime>2015-05-05T18:27:06</DateTime>
            <A>55465.359375</A>
            <B>1808040</B>
            <C>-331.424926757812</C>
            <D>-74553.75</D>
            <B>1808040</B>
            <F>-10100.994140625</F>
            <C>-331.424926757812</C>
            <G>-445363.5625</G>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <DateTime>2015-05-05T18:27:06</DateTime>
            <A>NA</A>
            <B>NA</B>
            <C>NA</C>
            <D>NA</D>
            <B>1808040</B>
            <F>NA</F>
            <C>NA</C>
            <G>NA</G>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <DateTime>2015-05-05T18:27:06</DateTime>
            <A>NA</A>
            <B>NA</B>
            <C>NA</C>
            <D>NA</D>
            <B>NA</B>
            <F>NA</F>
            <C>-331.424926757812</C>
            <G>NA</G>
        </Row>
    </Rowset>
</Rowsets>
```

I want my resultant XML as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<Rowsets CachedTime="" DateCreated="2015-05-05T19:27:06" EndDate="2015-05-05T19:27:06" StartDate="2015-05-05T18:27:06" Version="14.0.0 Build(802)">
    <Rowset>
        <Columns>
            <Column Description="DateTime" MaxRange="0" MinRange="0" Name="DateTime" SQLDataType="93" SourceColumn="DateTime"/>
            <Column Description="" MaxRange="0" MinRange="0" Name="_10LI132.PV" SQLDataType="6" SourceColumn="10LI132.PV"/>
            <Column Description="" MaxRange="0" MinRange="0" Name="_10LQ132.PV" SQLDataType="6" SourceColumn="10LQ132.PV"/>
            <Column Description="" MaxRange="0" MinRange="0" Name="_10TI112.PV" SQLDataType="6" SourceColumn="10TI112.PV"/>
            <Column Description="" MaxRange="0" MinRange="0" Name="_10LI135.PV" SQLDataType="6" SourceColumn="10LI135.PV"/>
            <Column Description="" MaxRange="0" MinRange="0" Name="_10LQ132.PV" SQLDataType="6" SourceColumn="10LQ132.PV"/>
            <Column Description="" MaxRange="0" MinRange="0" Name="_10LI127.PV" SQLDataType="6" SourceColumn="10LI127.PV"/>
            <Column Description="" MaxRange="0" MinRange="0" Name="_10TI112.PV" SQLDataType="6" SourceColumn="10TI112.PV"/>
            <Column Description="" MaxRange="0" MinRange="0" Name="_10LQ127.PV" SQLDataType="6" SourceColumn="10LQ127.PV"/>
        </Columns>
        <Row>
            <DateTime>2015-05-05T18:27:06</DateTime>
            <A>55465.359375</A>
            <B>1808040</B>
            <C>-331.424926757812</C>
            <D>-74553.75</D>
            <F>-10100.994140625</F>
            <G>-445363.5625</G>
        </Row>
    </Rowset>
</Rowsets>
```

PLease note that nodes ,  ets are dynamically generated so cannot hard-code them in XSLT.

Let me know if you hv got any ideas to solve my issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try so far? What is the criterion to remove those Row's?

Comment: I just need to keep first <Row>. All other <Row>s need to be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use xslt 2.0? If so, please see the stylesheet below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Rowset/Row[1]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by=".">
                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group( )[1]"/>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//Row[preceding-sibling::Row]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution to this question is to look at `Row`'s that have a `Row` before them and to look at elements that have one before them with the same name. With those - do nothing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="//Row[preceding-sibling::Row]"/>

    <xsl:template match="//Row/*[name() = preceding-sibling::*/name()]"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

All other elements get copied as they are.

Comment: Thanks Leu. This will remove all of subsequent <Row>s. But I also need ot remove duplicate nodes from first <Row>.